# Are usb ESD protection like the PRTR5V must have?

Tags: usb, protection, esd

I am making a custom pcb basing on Arduino's open source schematics and i noticed that their newer products always have a [PRTR5V0U2X](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PRTR5V0U2X.pdf) USB ESD protection wired like this:

[image]

Are they a must have if you are dealing with usb lines? Also how do they protect from electrostatic discharge ? judging from its diagram it is several diodes in a certain configuration

[image]

Its Ground pin and the usb shielding also does not directly go to ground they pass through C18 and R10 first.

Comment: Considering a person may touch, without grounding themselves, the connector or the plug, you may get ESD spikes up to 10KV. If you don't have the TVS in there, you risk damaging the circuit or downstream components. This is especially true of something you expect to be plugged in/unplugged often, but even in controlled environments (like your assembly shop) ESD can damage your equipment.